# undefined variable or method http while requesting an http connection

Tags: ruby

i am working on getting the lines from a wordlist, creating an account using the username and password as the word from the wordlist, and email also, but i get an error :

> 1gen.rb:42:in 'block in ': undefined local variable or method 'http' for m
>   ain:Object (NameError)
>           from 1gen.rb:35:in 'each_line'
>           from 1gen.rb:35:in 'main'

here is the code :

```
file=File.open('wordlist.txt' , 'r+')
            file.each_line do |line|
            gen = line.chomp
            puts gen
            path=("created1.txt")
            email = gen.to_s+'@gmail.com'
            password = gen.to_s
            username = gen.to_s+'/>'
            puts HackEx::Request.Do(http,HackEx::Request.CreateUser(username, email, password, facebook_id = nil))
            count +=1
            file.close
```

this is the faulty piece of code, i think i have an idea of what the error is, but i am a very beginner at ruby, all help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the `puts HackEx...` line you are using the identifier `http` which apparently you have not defined before using it.

Comment: this is just a small part, http is defined in a library

Comment: When you experience the error, http is not defined, period. The error is message is unambiguous and leaves no room for interpretation. You should now investigate why it is not defined despite your expectations. Possibilities: Different spelling, scoping rules, definition is not actually executed. You're on your own here unless you post a minimal but _complete_ example that someone else can execute and reproduce the error.

Comment: i know why its not defined, because it thinks that the variable is local, but its not, its from another file which i required #require_relative '../lib/hackex/net/typhoeus' anyway to unlocalize it ?

Comment: So it's scoping rules. Fix it. By the way, "it" does not "think". "It" just executes your code. But funny to read. A quick and dirty fix would be to make that http global: http -> $http. Both where it's defined and where it's used.